# Can you make a violinplot using only one data point and the quantiles calculated in python?

Tags: python, boxplot, violin-plot

I have a model that makes a prediction and intervals for the prediction of wine prices in python. To this i need som visualization of the finished product.

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a violin plot using only one data point and the interval as it is what my model does. I have done this for a boxplot, but wanted to have a different visualization.

I have created a boxplot this way using stats this way where price, q1, q3, interval_lower and interval_upper are all single datapoints that the model predicts:

```
stats = [{

"med": price,

"q1": q1,

"q3": q3,

"whislo": interval_lower,  # required

"whishi": interval_upper,  # required

"fliers": []  # required if showfliers=True

}]

fs = 10  # fontsize

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 6), sharey=True)

bp = axes.bxp(stats, patch_artist=True)

axes.set_title('Boxplot for wine prediction', fontsize=fs,color='Blue')

plt.show(bp)
```

This works fine for boxplots, but i cannot find a way to use violinplot in the same way. Does anyone know a way to do this? I'm using jupyter notebook for python.

Comment: The [official example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/customized_violin.html) of customizing a violin plot would be helpful.

Comment: I tried multiple things. The first thing i tried was just to do like the boxplot even though the matplotlib documentation says it needs an array. I did like this:

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 6), sharey=True)
bp = axes.violinplot(stats)
axes.set_title('Violinplot for wine prediction', fontsize=fs,color='Blue')

And got the error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict' and 'float'

Comment: Disable the link once you have confirmed this Colab.

Comment: I checked the code again and noticed that the example of this is how to customize a violin plot, so I apologize that it is not to create a new one from scratch.

Comment: Yeah i know how to create the violinplot like that as well. The problem is in my case i don't have an array like the "data" that is created in your example. I only have one prediction, like 130 dollars for a bottle of wine. I'm not sure it's possible - but with the boxplot i can take that prediction and create the confidence intervals and then visualize it with a boxplot.